# Let $f$ be an entire function, show that the following conditions imply that $f$ is constant.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, analytic-functions, entire-functions

Let $f$ be an entire function, show that the following conditions imply that $f$ is constant.

(i)  $f(\mathbb C)\cap\{x \in \mathbb{R} | x < 0 \}= \emptyset$

(ii) $f(\mathbb C)\cap\{x \in \mathbb{R} | 0 < x < 1 \}= \emptyset$

(iii) $f(\mathbb C)\cap\{z \in \mathbb{C} | |z - 1| < \frac{1}{4} \} = \emptyset$

I know how to prove the (iii) using Liouville's Theorem. I know that the $f(\mathbb C)$ is dense in $\mathbb{C}$ if $f$ is a nonconstant entire function.

Then the intersection of the range of $f$ with any open set in $\mathbb{C}$ can not be empty. But for (i) and (ii) I don't know because those two are not open sets in $\mathbb{C}$. Show I consider that sets as open sets in the relative topology?

Answer (score 3):

Throwing little Picard or the Riemann mapping theorem at (i) seems overkill to me. We just need to recall that the map

$$ g(z)= \frac{\sqrt z - 1}{\sqrt z + 1} $$

is biholomorphic from $ U = \mathbb C \setminus (-\infty,0] $ onto the open unit disc. So if $ f $ is entire and $ f(\mathbb C)\subset U, $ then $ g\circ f $ is a bounded entire function. Hence it is constant by Liouville. It follows that $f$ is constant.

Answer (score 2):

For the first, we can use the Riemann mapping theorem. The complex plane minus a line (here we take $x\leq -1$) is conformaly mapped to the unit disk. Let $g$ be that mapping. Now, take $h=g\circ f$. Observe that $h$ is a bounded entire function hence it is constant, which in turn implies that $f$ is constant.

For the second one, notice the set $\mathbb{C}- [a,b]   $ can be conformaly mapped to the unit disk minus a point. For instance when $a=0,b=1$ take $g= \dfrac{2}{1 + \sqrt{1 - \frac{1}{z}   }} -1$. Now, arguing as before we can conclude that $f$ is constant.

Comment: Why you can say that $h$ is bounded and entire? We do not know anything about that mapping $g$, how can I know that the composition is bounded and entire ?.

Comment: @RichardClare $g$ is from the Riemman mapping theorem, $g$ maps $\mathbb{C} - \{  x\leq -1 \}$ to the unit disk, and it is biholomorphic. Specifically, $|g| <1$ hence $|h|<1$, and since $g$ is holomorphic $h$ is holomoprhic as the composition of holomorphic functions.

Answer (score 1):

They all follow form the [little Picard theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard_theorem).

Comment: I'm aware of that theorem and that I can justify those problem using it. Unfortunately, my course did not cover that part of the book. I guess I should use another approach. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @RichardClare If there is another way of doing it, I would like to know it too.

Comment: Maybe how he prove that theorem will lead us to the answer, but I doubt that the proof of that theorem is based on the material covered by my course.

Comment: Take a look at the other solutions.

Comment: @RichardClare I'm confused. You are not supposed ti use the little Picard theorem but it is acceptable to use the Riemann mapping theorem?